# Access Query Issue - Cannot identify Error 3141

Tags: ms-access

this was working previously and now I cannot figure out where the error is. trying to create a design view table qry

all table and field references are named properly

```sql
SELECT
    Union.[HARD DOLLAR ENTRY AREA]
  , Union.Service
  , tblAcctCodes.QtyRollUpTo
  , tblAcctCodes.AcctCode
  , tblAcctCodes.Desc
  , Union.UOM
  , SUM(Union.QTY) AS SumOfQTY
  , Union.UR
  , Union.MH
  , tblAcctCodes.MH
  , tblAcctCodes.[Is Terminal]
  , [is terminal] & [qty]   AS Expr1
  , tblAcctCodes.[WBS Code] AS CBS
  , tblAcctCodes.Level
  , tblAcctCodes.[Calc]
  , [Calc] & [QTY] AS Expr2
FROM
    [Union]
    RIGHT JOIN
        tblAcctCodes
    ON
        Union.[Account Code] = tblAcctCodes.AcctCode
GROUP BY
    Union.[HARD DOLLAR ENTRY AREA]
  , Union.Service
  , tblAcctCodes.QtyRollUpTo
  , tblAcctCodes.AcctCode
  , tblAcctCodes.Desc
  , Union.UOM
  , Union.UR
  ,

 UNION

    .MH
  , tblAcctCodes.MH
  , tblAcctCodes.[Is Terminal]
  , [is terminal] & [qty]
  , tblAcctCodes.[WBS Code]
  , tblAcctCodes.Level
  , tblAcctCodes.[Calc]
  , [Calc] & [QTY]
HAVING
    (
        (
            (
                [is terminal] & [qty]
            )
            <>"Yes"
            OR
            (
                [is terminal] & [qty]
            )
            IS NULL
        )
    )
ORDER BY
    tblAcctCodes.QtyRollUpTo
;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve your question (edit)!

Comment: After formatting, query can be debugged (search for UNION-Query).

Comment: @ComputerVersteher: This is not a union query.

Comment: @Gustav: Oh, a table named UNION, I didn't expect that ;( I just recognized the lonely UNION and concluded a missing SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

Your originally posted code has a *space* too much:

```
Union.UR, 
UNION .MH, 
tblAcctCodes.MH
```

Also, don't use a reserved word (UNION) for a query name.